# Is there any solution for this error 402620388 message?

Tags: swift

I have searched 100s of things but not even one worked for me i deintegrate pods and reinstall it, delete data from derived data, clean xcode project , legacy settings but not worked for me. Please can you help me out there ?

```
Details

Unable to install "WWCD"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388
--
No code signature found.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE800801C)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001236ac81a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001236edf70 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010a827385 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001236edca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1654
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000123564e91 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4165
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010a95aa10 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010a95c652 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a4906c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a491658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a496c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a4975d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6a4a0c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a6eba3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6a6eab77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E266)
Xcode 11.4 (16134)
```

Comment: Did you do anything to do with code signing? The error message clearly states: "No code signature found."

Comment: @Anshul Garg, did u find a solution?

Comment: Had the same issue. You will find my answer here!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983562/xcode-cant-install-application/66116804#66116804

Answer (score 2):

WORK AROUND TO:
Unable to install "app"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620388

Apparently this is a known (SR-13343) in Xcode 12. It has to do with "SwiftPM binaryTarget dependency and code signing", where Xcode fails to sign the frameworks that are provided by SwiftPM.

See this link: https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftpm-binarytarget-dependency-and-code-signing/38953

If you read thru you will find a link to the work around, by adding a script to the build phase of the target:

Work Around: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/knowledge-base/library-not-found-swiftpm/

I just added the script to my app, everything is now good!

Answer (score 1):

For my case using Xcode 13

1. Remove all frameworks reference
2. Clear build folder
3. Clear DerivedData folder
4. Add back all the frameworks

Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me when my flutter version (stable) did not yet work well with the latest XCode version (11.4). I deleted the `/android` and `/ios` folders, ran `flutter create .` from my app folder to recreate them. Then I used Git to restore my modifications to the folders.

My project was in an early stage so this was a very quick fix. This may vary if you have a project with more modifications inside ios / android folders.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me on new Xcode 12. Finally I realised that I included wrong target of the third-party library trough Swift Package Manager.

So I suggest to check third-party libs included in your project, because there can be easily something wrong with signing.